# File path format in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt file generated by Yomen , there is a file path define as

```
test: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
  },
  src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
}
```

What is the meaning of `'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'` what does it match ?
also I have seen many places `js/**/*.js` , does this mean all the folders in js ?

Comment: `js/**/*.js` means all .js files in all subdirectories of js directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`node-glob` documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer), the brace-enclosed portion of the glob expands the comma-delimited sections within the braces. So this:

```
['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
```

should expand to this:

```
['test/spec/*.js', 'test/spec/*/*.js']
```

matching any `.js` files in `test/spec` or in any directory immediately under `test/spec`.

That's a slightly different to `'test/spec/**/*.js'`, which will match any `.js` files in `test/spec` and in any directory - no matter how deep - under `test/spec`.